# How to verify the root trust of a ceritifcate

Tags: java, digital-signature, x509certificate, client-certificates

I am new to java security.
I have a certificate which is signed with a self signed root certificate .Say client.pem is the signed certificate and root.pem is the root certificate.

The signed certificate is embedded into the client program.

When connection is made it to the server program.

Ineed to verify the call is  from authenticate client.The client shall sent its certificate to the server.

I need to check whether cleint.pem is actually signed with root.pem using Java API.

i have some idea about java.security.cert.Certificate.verify(PublicKey key) method to verify two same certificates.But is this will be useful to verify root of trust ?

can any please help ?

thanks
abhi

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does exactly that: clientCert.verify(rootCert.getPublicKey()) checks that clientCert was signed with the private key of root